# Efficient matrix-product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, machine-learning, optimal-transport

Do you know please how to write this in a matrix form in order to be able to calculate this amount efficiently in numpy? D0 is a (n0,n0) matrix, D is a (n,n) matrix, mu0 is (n0,1) and mu is (n,1). Maybe it is not necessary to write this in a matrix form and there is an easy command with numpy to write 4 loops, I do know know.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSJ7n.png)

$$
\overline{\mathrm{GW}}_2^2(\mathbf D_0, \mathbf D) := 
\min_{\Gamma \in \overline{\mathcal M}}
\sum_{ijk\ell}(\mathbf D_{0ij}- \mathbf D_{k\ell})^2 \mathbf \Gamma_{ik} \mathbf\Gamma_{j\ell} \boldsymbol\mu_{0i}\boldsymbol\mu_{0j}\boldsymbol\mu_k\boldsymbol\mu_\ell.
$$

Comment: I suggest that you read the numpy documentation on Linear Algebra.

Comment: In fact i know numpy well but I am stuck on the mathematical part.

Comment: @Marcel I suspect that [einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) should be able to deal with this without much trouble

Comment: @BenGrossmann oh thanks !